# urged him to "come through"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I guess "urged him to 'come through'" means "urged him to overcome difficulites (to succeed)".

Cambridge Dictionary defines "come through" as "to succeed in a difficult situation". So Trump implies that Pence should be brave under pressure and get his job done.  I am not sure.

> Vice-President Mike Pence - who as president of the Senate is due to oversee the session and declare Mr Biden the winner - said he welcomed the move.
> .................
> By US election law, Mr Pence's duty in the proceedings is purely administrative, but Mr Trump has **urged his vice-president to "come through"**.

Source:  [BBC    US Congress set to certify Joe Biden victory amid protests](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-55555074)

Comment: Hi. Don't forget dictionaries! if you Google ***"come through" meaning*** you will get lots of definitions.  In this context I agree with your interpretation.  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22come+thtough%22+meaning&atb=v245-1&ia=web

Comment: I'd interpret this as the [first definition here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20through) of "come through", meaning "to do what is needed or expected."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context I agree with your interpretation.

P.S. Don't forget dictionaries! if you Google ***"come through" meaning*** you will get lots of definitions. [Come through - DucKDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22come+thtough%22+meaning&atb=v245-1&ia=web)

Here's a suitable definition:

> TRANSITIVE (come through something) to be still alive, working, or
> making progress after a difficult or dangerous experience It’s been a
> very upsetting time but we’ve come through it together
> https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-through